# Developing a website for 3 specific resolutions

Tags: wordpress, css

I've been tasked with developing a wordpress site for my company with almost 0 web development experience. I've been fiddling with CSS a bit and I've come up with this steaming pile of trash.

Anyways, I only need to develop it for 3 resolutions (Company standards). However, auto-scaling websites are complete magic to me. So I've decided to hardcode elements for each of 3 specific resolutions (1920x1080, 1440x900, 1024x768).

*Here's the code:*

**768 Users**

```
 @media (min-width : 768px) 
 {
    .sidebar 
    {
        right: 115px;
        bottom: 40px;
    }
 }
```

**900 Users**

```
 @media only screen and (min-width : 900px) and (max-width: 900px)
 {
    .sidebar 
    {
        right: 155px;
        bottom: 65px;
    }
 }
```

**1080 Users**

```
 @media only screen and (min-width : 1080px) 
 {
    .sidebar 
    {
        right: 155px;
        bottom: 65px;
    }
 }
```

**Diagram**
[image: visualization]

> **Question:**
>
> The issue is, the hardcoded scaling I've done only works for
> the */768 Users/* and the */1080 Users/*.
>
> Every change I make in the */900 Users/* section does nothing, how do I fix that?

Comment: Your formatting is all screwed up. Code should **not** be blockquoted, but should be formatted as code using the `{}` toolbar button instead. And it's not necessary to **bold** every **other** word **in** your **question**, and it's even more unnecessary to mix **bold and *italic bold* and more bold** all through your post. Post the question portion as text, and the code portion as code, properly formatted. I was going to edit it for you, but it's such a mess I gave up. Please [edit] it to format it properly; you can preview the post in WYSIWYG fashion right below where you're typing it.

Comment: The bolding is meant for skimming. IT people use this for lazy users to quickly understand something by only reading the bold. sorry.
the quotes make it easier to split up the code into sections. But I'll remove it. Please don't be so condescending.

Comment: The blockquote is incorrect. You blockquote content that isn't yours that you're including, like a citation from a book or documentation. As I said, your formatting is a mess and should be corrected. If you find the need to **bold** text excessively to allow people to **skim**, it's a sign you have too much noise or your text is unclear. And I don't need advice on what *IT people* do, thanks. I've been an IT person since probably before you were born. :-) I've never found the need to **excessively bold** text when writing documentation.

Comment: [excessiveblockqoute] Please don't be so condescending [/excessiveblockquote]

Comment: Wow. Childish response to constructive criticism and helpful advice noted. Won't make the mistake of trying to help you again in the future. Good luck.

Comment: You gave good advice, and I thank you. But theres no reason to be-little me.

Comment: I never belittled you. Read my first comment again. Then read your response, where you presumed to lecture me about what *IT people* do. Then read my next comment, where I continued to give you constructive advice.(Note that *IT people* frequently use **:-)** to indicate a smile, which means they've tried to say something humorous while you're reading it.) Then read your next comment starting with *[excessiveblockquote]* and tell me who was being *belittling*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150454/discussion-between-dylan-grove-and-ken-white).

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `(min-width : 900px) and (max-width: 900px)` will only target a width of exactly 900px, which is not desirable.

One technique is to use a "mobile-first implementation" in which you start with the smallest size first and work your way up. Think of it as styling for the smallest viewports first and then adding to those styles for increasingly larger viewports.

For example:

```css
/* start with smallest "mobile viewport" styles here, as a default */

@media (min-width : 768px) {
    /* add styles for 768px and up */
}
@media (min-width : 900px) { 
    /* add styles for 900px and up */
}
@media (min-width : 1080px) {
    /* add styles for 1080px and up */
}
```

You might find this article informative: [An Introduction to Mobile-First Media Queries](https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-mobile-first-media-queries/)

Comment: this is technically the better (and correct) answer

Comment: I tried this and what ends up happening is:
1080 users: Works perfect, 
900 users: No changes (not working), 
768 users: Receiving the changes from the 900 users section

Comment: Yes, they will be additive or overwriting. Can you put together a working example of what you've got so we can take a look?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/hMWIp (Its an internal website, all I can do is show screenshots)

Answer (score 1):

`@media only screen and (min-width : 900px) and (max-width: 900px)`  meaning from 900px to 900px.... so nowhere at all.

If I understand your problem correctly, this should work:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 900px) and (max-width:  1080px)
```

Comment: I've also tried this and it has the same effect as newman's answer

Answer (score 1):

Your going to use CSS3 media queries to essentially define each viewport you are supporting; and from within write your styles per. There a few ways to call this - but I've found the below the simplest to test starting out... You will also have to make sure your meta viewport tag from within the HTML doc is properly defined.

```
@media (max-width:900px) and (min-width:400px) {
    .foo {
        display:none;
    }
}​
```

Comment: Ive tried this and this time, it does this: 1080 users: Works Perfect, 900 users: No change (not working), 768 Users: Works perfect.

Comment: CSS properties that are not being updated within certain resolutions; you may have to define, redundantly; in the failing resolutions (or redefine within resolutions where it should be inherit)